# Is it possible to provide an ordering guarantee for a collection?

Tags: c#, collections, rank, contract, preserve

I'm trying to create a method which (other than in name) shows that the ordering of some collection will be preserved.

I have considered `SortedList`, but dismissed it due to the requirement of holding a key.  I have also dismissed other Sorted types for similar reasons, and `SortedSet` due to `Linq` returning `IEnumerable` instead of another `SortedSet` when you operate on it.

I don't mind if a new type is required, or I need to write methods in a specific way.  The goal here is to highlight methods which preserve the input order of a collection when operating upon it.

I had thought about adding a custom attribute and just trusting that it will be used correctly, but I would ideally like to find something in the language which is more explicit.

-- Edit

It's not so much the order of the elements in the collection (I could use an `IEnumerable`), but some operation on the input collection. Let's say I were returning the root of all the numbers in an array, instead of returning `(root, number)[]`, or `(root, index)[]` I want to return `root[]` and have it clear to the user that the order of the elements in the returned array matches the order of the elements in the input parameter.

Comment: By `ordering` , do you mean `A-Z` , `0-9` , `Smallest to Largest`, etc?

Comment: So, if I add elements A, X, Y, B, M, and G, that order is preserved?  There's no sorting going on, only preserving the initial ordering?  The standard List class pretty much does that if you no-op the Insert-ish methods.

Comment: Apply your sort and add to a queue to ensure order is preserved? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: "SortedSet due to Linq returning IEnumerable instead of another SortedSet when you operate on it." That's going to rule out literally any possible collection, either already existing, or that could ever exist, because the LINQ methods will *never* return any such collection.  It sounds like you just need `SortedSet`, and that's it.  You'll either need to write your own methods to perform complex queries on that collection, or re-create a new sorted collection based on the results of a LINQ query, if you want to use LINQ.

Comment: @Symon For any good ordered collection that would be determined by a comparer, not built into the collection itself.

Comment: `IList<T>` implies order because its elements can be accessed by index. Is that not sufficient?

Comment: Please see edit.  Essentially I care about highlighting intent to other developers, ideally without having this in codedoc or in the name of the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is nothing in C# or .Net that let you express and enforce "this method does not change order of elements in a collection / while iterating through collection".

Conventional expectation is order of elements stored in a collection preserved while iterating unless method/class explicitly named to indicate reordering.

Examples of "no reordering":

- `for` / 'foreach`
- `.Select`, `.First`, `.Take`, `.SelectMany`, `.Where`
- indexing of collection that is not called "SortedXxxxx" - `List`, array.

Examples of "does reordering"

- `List.Sort`, `List.Reverse`
- `.OrderBy`, `.ThenBy`
- classes that don't preserve/guarantee ordering like `HashSet`, `Dictionary`, `OrderedDictionary`, `SortedList`

Comment: There may not be a way to enforce it, but is there a way to convey it to another programmer without putting it in the name of the method?

It's not so much the order of the elements in the collection (I could use an IEnumerable), but some operation on the input collection.  

Let's say I were returning the root of all the numbers in an array, instead of returning (root, number), or (root, index) I want to return (root) and have it clear to the user that the order of the elements in the returned array matches the order of the elements in the input parameter.

Comment: I feel as though I may be asking too much of .NET for this one.

Comment: @Stevey no one will ever expect `IEnumerable<double> SquareRoots(IEnumerable<double> input)` to return items in order different then original collection. You may be way overthinking it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a [queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1?view=netframework-4.7.2). The first object added will be the first removed, so order of insertion is preserved. Typically objects are processed out of the queue with the `Dequeue()` method, but there is a `Peek()` method if you don't want to remove from the collection.

Beyond that, you'll probably need to roll your own implementation. It would likely just be a wrapper around a `List<T>`, where you prevent anything from being `Insert`ed.